# Can I round a PANDAS dataframe column in the same line that I edit the column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding, data-conversion

Using Python 3.9

Using PANDAS, I'm trying to convert a column from feet to meters and then round the answer to three decimals. I currently have this:

```
df['col_m'] = df[col_f] * 0.3048
df['col_m'] = df['col_m'].round(3)
```

It gets the job done but is there a more efficient way to do this? Is it possible to do both actions in one line? I tried a couple different methods but the rounding ends up occurring too early if not separated like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(df[col_f] * 0.3048).round(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform it in one step, just chain the operations. Using [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) in place of `*` makes it more convenient as you won't need parentheses (in comparison to `(df[col_f] * 0.3048).round(3)`):

```
df['col_m'] = df[col_f].mul(0.3048).round(3)
```